# decompile and recompile tomcat-coyote.jar

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to debugg tomcat-coyote, in order to modify Cookies.class and CookieSupport.class.
I've used Java Decompiler for extracte and modify the source code.

After this, I recompile my folder (tomcat-coyote) with this commande:

> jar cf tomcat-coyote.jar tomcat-coyote

But when i start my localhost with my new tomcat-coyote in the lib folder, the server doesn't run, and I got this error:

> Server Tomcat 7 failed to start.

is it-some have already faced the problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you compiled source file? jar cf tomcat-coyote.jar tomcat-coyote commond just creates a jar, it doesn't compile your java files.

Answer (score 4):

Do not decompile code if you want to debug it. The line numbers will never be as in source code. Tomcat is open source. Just download it as zip or even better check it out from source control. Then debug it.

Comment: I wish I could give more than +1 to this answer. Decompiling software whose source is freely available is a colossal waste of time.